# Ionic 4 Column Placement In NgFor Loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the NgFor once. I want to achieve this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxaXj.png). This code works but I don't want to loop through it twice

> ```
> <ion-row>
>   <ng-container *ngFor="let it of (item | async)?.sections">
>     <ng-container *ngIf="it.name !== 'Account' && it.name !== 'Settings'">
>       <ion-col size="{{it.size}}">
>         <div>
>           <ion-card class="alone {{it.color}}">
>             <ion-card-header>
>               <ion-img [src]="'/assets/images/'+it.icon"></ion-img>
>               <ion-card-title>{{it.name}}</ion-card-title>
>             </ion-card-header>
>           </ion-card>
>         </div>
>       </ion-col>
>     </ng-container>
>   </ng-container>
>   <ion-col size="2"> <--- SHOW IT ONCE
>     <ng-container *ngFor="let it of (item | async)?.sections">
>       <ng-container *ngIf="it.name === 'Account' || it.name === 'Settings'">
>         <ion-row align-items-center>
>           <div style="width: 100%">
>             <ion-card class="{{it.color}}">
>               <ion-card-header>
>                 <ion-img [src]="'/assets/images/'+it.icon"></ion-img>
>                 <ion-card-title>{{it.name}}</ion-card-title>
>               </ion-card-header>
>             </ion-card>
>           </div>
>         </ion-row>
>       </ng-container>
>     </ng-container>
>   </ion-col>
> </ion-row>
> ```

If I try to combine both loops it gives me two columns

> ```
> <ion-row>
>   <ng-container *ngFor="let it of (item | async)?.sections">
>     <ng-container *ngIf="it.name !== 'Account' && it.name !== 'Settings'">
>       <ion-col size="{{it.size}}">
>         <div>
>           <ion-card class="alone {{it.color}}">
>             <ion-card-header>
>               <ion-img [src]="'/assets/images/'+it.icon"></ion-img>
>               <ion-card-title>{{it.name}}</ion-card-title>
>             </ion-card-header>
>           </ion-card>
>         </div>
>       </ion-col>
>     </ng-container>
>     <ng-container *ngIf="it.name === 'Account' || it.name === 'Settings'">
>       <ion-col size="2"> <--- WILL BE PRINTED TWICE
>         <ion-row align-items-center>
>           <div style="width: 100%">
>             <ion-card class="{{it.color}}">
>               <ion-card-header>
>                 <ion-img [src]="'/assets/images/'+it.icon"></ion-img>
>                 <ion-card-title>{{it.name}}</ion-card-title>
>               </ion-card-header>
>             </ion-card>
>           </div>
>         </ion-row>
>       </ion-col>
>     </ng-container>
>   </ng-container>
> </ion-row>
> ```

If I try to do something link `*ngIf="(index % 3) == 0"` it would print the column once but I wont be able to enter the second time to print Row2 in that same column.

I'm not sure if it's possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ng-template` to share the same logic

### https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description

```
<ion-row>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let it of (item | async)?.sections">
        <ng-container *ngIf="it.name !== 'Account' && it.name !== 'Settings'">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="col; context: it"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ion-col size="2">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let it of (item | async)?.sections">
            <ng-container *ngIf="it.name === 'Account' || it.name === 'Settings'">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="row; context: it"></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ng-template #col let-it="it">

    <ion-col size="{{it.size}}">
        <div>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cardHeader; context: it"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </ion-col>

</ng-template>

<ng-template #row>

    <ion-row align-items-center>
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="card; context: it"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </ion-row>

</ng-template>

<ng-template #card let-it="it">

    <ion-card class="{{it.color}}">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-img [src]="'/assets/images/'+it.icon"></ion-img>
            <ion-card-title>{{it.name}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>

</ng-template>
```